# How does one correctly convert a java string from one encoding to another encoding?

Tags: java, internationalization, turkish

I have been working with i18n stuff for a while and thought I knew a lot about this. But I am testing something and the more I look at it, the worse it gets.

We start with a string:  Boğaziçi Üniversitesi

It was sent to us by our rich-client application (running Windows and using windows-1254), interpreted as ISO-8859-1 (don't ask) and saved in a MySQL database. Now, in the database, I see the character values below, which can be interpreted as windows-1254 as so:

```
42 6f f0 61 7a 69 e7 69 20 dc 6e 69 76 65 72 73 69 74 65 73 69
 B  o  ğ  a  z  i  ç  i     Ü  n  i  v  e  r  s  i  t  e  s  i
```

So far, so good. This looks to be the correct form of the string.

But, here is what one gets by running getBytes() on the string, with either no or different encodings:

BU.getBytes(): (21)  42 6f    3f 61 7a 69    8d 69 20    86 6e 69 76 65 72 73 69 74 65 73 69

BU.getBytes(windows-1254): (21)  42 6f    3f 61 7a 69    e7 69 20    dc 6e 69 76 65 72 73 69 74 65 73 69

BU.getBytes(ISO-8859-1): (21)  42 6f    f0 61 7a 69    e7 69 20    dc 6e 69 76 65 72 73 69 74 65 73 69

BU.getBytes(UTF8): (24)  42 6f c3 b0 61 7a 69 c3 a7 69 20 c3 9c 6e 69 76 65 72 73 69 74 65 73 69

So, looking at the last one, one has to wonder where the "ð" came from.

```
42 6f c3 b0 61 7a 69 c3 a7 69 20 c3 9c 6e 69 76 65 72 73 69 74 65 73 69
B  o      ð  a  z  i     ç  i        Ü  n  i  v  e  r  s  i  t  e  s  i
```

From http://rishida.net/tools/conversion/, this is what I would expect to get for values in a valid UTF-8 string:

```
42 6f C4 9F 61 7a 69 C3 A7 69 20 C3 9C 6e 69 76 65 72 73 69 74 65 73 69
 B  o     ğ  a  z  i     ç  i        Ü  n  i  v  e  r  s  i  t  e  s  i
```

*Removing last part of question here and replacing with.*

This code:

```
byte BU_Array[] = new byte[] { (byte)0x42, (byte)0x6F, (byte)0xF0, (byte)0x61,
   (byte)0x7A, (byte)0x69,(byte)0xE7, (byte)0x69, (byte)0x20, (byte)0xDC, 
   (byte)0x6E, (byte)0x69, (byte)0x76, (byte)0x65, (byte)0x72, (byte)0x73, 
    (byte)0x69, (byte)0x74, (byte)0x65, (byte)0x73, (byte)0x69 };

    try {
        String BU_Str_ISO88591 = new String(BU_Array, "ISO-8859-1");
        System.out.println("BU_Str_ISO88591   cP: "+codePointsToHex(BU_Str_ISO88591));

        String BU_Str_W1254 = new String(BU_Array, "windows-1254");
        System.out.println("BU_Str_W1254      cP: "+codePointsToHex(BU_Str_W1254));

        byte bytes_possibly_as_utf8[] = BU_Str_W1254.getBytes("UTF-8");
        System.out.println("bytes from BU_Str_W1254: "+Utilities.bytesToHex(bytes_possibly_as_utf8));

    } catch (java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
        uee.printStackTrace();
    }
```

produces:

```
BU_Str_ISO88591 cP: (21): 42 6f f0 61 7a 69 e7 69 20 dc 6e 69 76 65 72 73 69 74 65 73 69
BU_Str_W1254 cP: (21): 42 6f 11f 61 7a 69 e7 69 20 dc 6e 69 76 65 72 73 69 74 65 73 69
bytes from BU_Str_W1254: (24)  42 6f c4 9f 61 7a 69 c3 a7 69 20 c3 9c 6e 69 76 65 72 73 69 74 65 73 69
```

What was confusing here is the 3rd character in the 1st line.

When I took a string that had been given to us as windows-1254, but which we interpreted as iso-8859-1, the code point for the 3rd character is f0. Which is the correct character in windows-1254. Huh? Was that just a coincidence? I doubt it, but the logic seems convoluted.

So, I think I answered my own question here.

Comment: I see lots of information, but virtually no code. Code is worth 1,024 words! Show the actual code you're using that's performing the conversion that isn't working.

Comment: Java `String`s are UTF-16 encoded.  Only `byte[]` can be encoded different ways.

Comment: To expand on @PeterLawrey's comment, within a Java program there is no choice about String encoding: it's always UTF-16.  The only time encoding choices must be made is when converting between String and byte[]. The most common reason for this conversion is input or output, since I/O devices handle data as octet (byte) streams.